# Azure Windows VM: Correct amount logical processors not delivered for M128s standard

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I am trying to deploy a Windows virtual machine with 128 logical processors. For that purpose, I have selected the following configuration:

- Subscription: Pay-As-You-Go Operating
- System: Windows 10 Pro
- Size:
- Standard M128s (128 vcpus, 2048 GiB memory)
- Azure Spot: Price or
  capacity

The virtual machine is deployed correctly. However, when I go to the Task Manager and check the CPU performance I find out that it only has 64 logical processors, instead of the promised 128. More details:

- Sockets: 2
- Virtual processors: 64

Have someone has had the same issue and could offer a solution?

Comment: May I know if you enabled Hyper-V?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry that [Hyper-V Limits the Maximum Number of Processors in the Hyper-V Host OS to 64](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2812283/hyper-v-limits-the-maximum-number-of-processors-in-the-hyper-v-host-os)

The article talks abour Windows Server 2012, but I have searched a lot and found that Windows 2016 also has the same limit:

[image]

As you were creating a VM (which I think is based on Hyper-V from Azure platform), so I think that is why you can only see 64 virtual processors in task manager.